# Create equal groups of timings

Tags: python, sql, grouping

Pretty tricky one here. I have a data warehouse that runs different load jobs. I have all the load jobs in batches. I have the timings for all the load jobs and want a way to programmatically work out the best way to arrange the load jobs into separate batches to make them all finish around the same time.

My data looks like this:

```
NAME    TIME
AA_1    13:52.9
AA_2    10:37.8
AA_3    10:10.6
AA_4    09:07.7
AA_5    08:22.9
AA_6    04:29.3
AA_7    04:14.4
AA_8    03:56.3
AA_9    03:11.4
AA_10   02:59.3
```

As an example if I take AA_1 and AA_2 then their run time will be around 24 minutes. If I think take AA_3, AA_4 and AA_6 it'll be around 24 minutes too.

So basically I want to be able to specify that I want this to be split up into an `n` number of batches and then have the program work out the best groupings.

Any thoughts? I'm happy to do it in Python or SQL.

Thanks

Comment: This is kind of a scheduling problem... Sould it be efficient? Or could it be a greedy or compare all with all (N^2)?